# Mostrar tabla en sql

Tags: php

Como puedo recorrer la variable users para que me muestre la tabla:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';



$database_connection = database_connect();

$users = $database_connection->query('SELECT * FROM tabla')->fetchAll();




$title = 'Home';
$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<table>
<th>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspName&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTitle&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspola&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
</th>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
';
include 'Template.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> Valores devueltos
>
> PDOStatement::fetchAll() devuelve un array que contiene tadas las filas restantes del conjunto de resultados. El array representa cada fila como un array con valores de las columnas, o como un objeto con propiedades correspondientes a cada nombre de columna. Es devuelto un array vacío si hay cero resultados que obtener, o FALSE en caso de fallo.

Por consiguiente un simple foreach ([ver documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)) lo puede recorrer:

```
<?php

// ...

$users = $database_connection->query('SELECT * FROM tabla')->fetchAll();

foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $user['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user['phone']; ?></td>
<?php }
```

Comment: esto lo puedo hacer dentro de content?? Puedo usar funciones para hacer esto ?? en mi caso estoy haciendo una pagina solamente en php para incluir un template en html  con php

Comment: ¿Qué es "content"? ¿Te refieres a funciones personalizadas?

Comment: Te pongo el codigo modificando el post que es el que estoy utilizando si tienes tiempo compruebalo y veras a lo que me refiero gracias de nuevo

Comment: no puedo incluir mi consutla dentro del template

Answer (score 2):

El problema no está en el foreach, sino que está en cómo se está haciendo el template y cómo al poner `<?php .... ?>` dentro de la cadena se "rompe" la página:

```
<?php

...

$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<table>
<th>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspName&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTitle&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspola&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
</th>

    <tr>
        <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <td><?php echo $user["id"]?></td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>


</table>
';
```

(puedes ver como incluso el formateador de código de StackOverflow colorea la parte del foreach de forma diferente después del primer `?>`)

Para solucionar esto habría que saber qué hace Template.php (¿usas algún framework?) y averiguar cómo crear un bucle con datos dentro del mismo... o simplemente generar la cadena directamente antes de pasársela al Template (lo cual será mucho más sencillo y debería funcionar sin problemas):

```
$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<table>
<th>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspName&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTitle&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspola&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
</th>

    <tr>';


foreach($users as $user) {
    $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["id"] . '</td>';
}


$content .= '</tr>


</table>
';
```

---

El código final quedaría así (ya no hará falta el foreach del final porque se habrá arreglado antes).

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';



$database_connection = database_connect();

$users = $database_connection->query('SELECT id FROM coffee')->fetchAll();


$title = 'Home';
$content = '
<h4>Title 1</h4>
<table>
<th>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspName&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTitle&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspola&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
</th>

    <tr>';

foreach($users as $user) {
    $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["id"] . '</td>';
}

$content .= '</tr>


</table>
';

include 'Template.php';
      ?>
```

Comment: Gracias maestro

Comment: una pregunta porque cuando hago esto: foreach($users as $user) {
    $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["name"] . '</td>';
    echo "<br/>";
    $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["type"] . '</td>';
    
    
} no me hace el salto de linea y me muestra los campos juntos

Comment: es muy ultima duda como puedo hacer salto de lineas entre los diferentes campos?

Comment: @OmarAlami Dentro de una cadena los saltos de línea en PHP se hacen con `\n` en lugar de con `<br>` (que es HTML). Entonces l que tendrías que hacer es algo como esto: `foreach($users as $user) { $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["name"] . '</td>\n'; $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["type"] . '</td>\n'; }`

Comment: no me hace el salto??

Comment: simplemente me muestra esto encima de la tabla \n\n\n\n\n\n

Comment: Oops! Son comillas simples entonces no se escapa bien, intenta concatenar PHP_EOL o ponerlo en comillas dobles. Algo como esto: `foreach($users as $user) { $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["name"] . "</td>\n"; $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["type"] . "</td>\n"; }`, o como esto otro: `foreach($users as $user) { $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["name"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL; $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["type"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL; }`

Comment: lo intente hacer tambien pero sigue apareciendo junto basicamente lo que hago es esto: foreach($users as $user) { $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["name"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL; $content = $content . '<td>' . $user["type"] . '</td>' . PHP_EOL; }
$content .=  '</tr> y lo que sigue.. intente del otro modo pero sigue junto puede que falte algun detalle?

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar a qué te refieres con salto de línea? Creo que no estoy entendiéndolo bien

Comment: a esto: https://i.imgsafe.org/577a93d262.png

Comment: Lo que quieres es poner cada nombre en una fila, para eso mueve el `<tr>` y el `</tr>` a dentro del foreach: `foreach($users as $user) {
    $content = $content . '<tr><td>' . $user["id"] . '</td></tr>';
}`

Comment: vale muchas gracias me va ser muy util tus ejemplos

Comment: mil graciasssss

Comment: @OmarAlami Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, considerá aceptarla haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda de la misma (ambos se benefician). Más información en [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). También deberías votar a favor de todas las respuestas que te parecieron útiles.